# Devexpress - How to open a form as a tabbed view

Tags: winforms, devexpress

I have a Ribbon Form with a treelist on the left so i put a XtraUserControl to insert a DocumentManager in which i would like to add all my tabbed forms (like in Visual Studio).
How can i do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I suggedt you start from the [How to: Display Documents Using a Tabbed UI](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument11361) example. The main idea of this example is that you can add the DocumentManager onto the form and then handle a treelist item's Click to add all needed child forms as MDI-children - the DocumentManager will track all the changes automatically:

```
Form childForm = new Form();
childForm.MdiParent = this;
childForm.Show();
```

To read more about the another Document Manager concepts and features please refer to the corresponding [documentation articles](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument11856).

Comment: I resolved putting a dockpanel on the left and assigning the DocumentManager to the main form. All forms within it fit exacltly where i want.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void Viewchild(Form _form)
    {
        //Check Before Open
        if (!IsFormActive(_form))
        {
            _form.MdiParent = this;
            _form.Show();
        }
    }
    //Check If a Form Is Opened Already
    private bool IsFormActive(Form form)
    {
        bool IsOpened = false;
        //If There Is More Than One Form Opened
        if (MdiChildren.Count() > 0)
        {
            foreach (var item in MdiChildren)
            {
                if (form.Name == item.Name)
                {
                    // Active This Form
                    xtraTabbedMdiManager1.Pages[item].MdiChild.Activate();
                    IsOpened = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return IsOpened;
    }
```

open form in 
 Master.frmBranch fb = new Master.frmBranch();
            fb.Name = "frmBranch";